# Why I can't upload a favicon.ico as an Asset?

Tags: assets

I'm unable to upload the favicon.ico thought Craft because it says:

`Upload failed for favicon.ico. The error message was: ”Error uploading the file: This file type is not allowed“`

1. Why does that restriction exists? I just couldn't find a list of forbidden files.
2. Can I change that restriction?

I know I can use a FTP client to put the file in the folder, but since I'm doing this site for a friend I just wanted to leave her an easy way of managing the icon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) It's not allowed because it's currently not in the [allowedFileExtensions](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#allowedFileExtensions) config setting.

2) Just add 'ico' to the [extraAllowedFileExtensions](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#extraAllowedFileExtensions) config setting and you'll be able to upload .ico file.

Comment: I forgot to check the config file, thanks!